# Asus Laptop Touchpad Not Working on Ubuntu 14.04 or Greater Versions (Elantech Touchpad)

Tags: touchpad, asus, elantech

On Asus laptop, the Elantech Touchpad is not working. Does anyone know about the fix?

Comment: What are the errors or issues...?

Comment: External mouse is working, but laptop touchpad is not working

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Terminal and run the following command

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Find the line with text "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" and modify it as given bellow:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"
   ```
3. Now update the grub to make the changes effect by running the update-grub command given bellow:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Now restart your laptop to make the touchpad work.